# All my system settings disappeared!

Tags: sound, system, settings

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and am having some problems..

Today I noticed that no sound was being output at all while I was in Ubuntu.  I am dual-booting with Windows 8, where the sound works perfectly so I know it's not hardware.

I tried everything I could find on the internet, to no avail, my sound just will not work (for some reason all of my systems say the MAX sound level is 0.00 Db, which is strange...?)

I eventually found this suggestion here on askUbuntu:

"Try first to reload ALSA:

sudo alsa force-reload
If that won't help, try to reinstall ALSA and pulseaudio:

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio"

I tried the second suggestion, and now ALL of my system settings are completely gone from my computer. All that is left is language support, and Landscape Service. No audio, wifi, bluetooth, printer, etc... I have tried everything but I can't get these back!

Does anyone have any ideas where they might have gone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update:  I just tried using my headphones: Sound works perfectly for them, even though there is no  audio settings available anymore.  Although, sound through speakers is still non-existent :(

Answer (score 0):

- For system setting problem, try to run this :
  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
- For your sound problem, do a real shutdown from windows 8 (not reboot or standby) and test  .
- If not ok , test also this command to reset pulseaudio config:
  `rm -fr .pulse`
  and restart pulseaudio running this 2 commands:
  `pulseaudio -k`
  then
  `pulseaudio -D`